# How to pass database record from Controller to View in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've started a project in CakePHP. I have no experience of it, most of my experience is with Symfony2.

Right now, I have built a view file, a controller, and a model for use with this project and it's database. In one controller I want to pass one record from the database to the view for use on the homepage. However, I'm unable to pass the record as I get this error:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: content [APP\View\Contents\home.ctp,
>   line 42]

Here is my controller code:

```
function home() {
    $content = $this->Content->query("SELECT title, content FROM content WHERE id = 1;");
    $this->set('pagecontent',$content); 
}
```

And here is the code I'm using to display the data in the view file:

```
<?php $content['content']; ?>
```

What have I missed?

---

**EDIT:**
I have changed the `<?php $content['content']; ?>` to  `<?php echo $pagecontent['Content']['content']; ?>` inline with the changes outlined in the answer from Ross. However, there is now this error:

> Notice (8): Undefined index: Content [APP\View\Contents\home.ctp, line
>   43]

I have used the `<?php echo debug($this->viewVars); ?>` and this is the output from that:

```
 app\View\Contents\home.ctp (line 42) Array (
     [pagecontent] => Array
         (
             [0] => Array
                 (
                     [content] => Array
                         (
                             [title] => <h1>This is a title</h1>
                             [content] => <p>this is some test text</p>
                         )

                 )

         )

 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->set('pagecontent',$content);` - this is where you are setting view variables.

You are trying to access a variable called `$content`, when in fact it is stored as `$pagecontent`.

Also based on Cake conventions, the key `content` should actually be `Content`, so your output should probably be:

```
<h1><?php echo $pagecontent['Content']['title']; ?></h1>
<div class="page-content">
    <?php echo $pagecontent['Content']['content']; ?>
</div>
```

You can always do `debug($this->viewVars);` to see exactly what you have access to.

---

Seeing the output helps; the error is due to how cake is returning the data.

This is likely due to you using `query()` rather than `find()` or `read()`. (also explains why your `content` key is lowercase - `query()` [uses the table name](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1027/query), rather than the model name.

Try:

```
$content = $this->Content->find('first', 
                              array('fields' => array('title', 'content'),
                                    'conditions' => array('Content.id' => 1)
                                   )
                               );

$this->set('pagecontent', $content); 


// view
echo $pagecontent['Content']['title'];
echo $pagecontent['Content']['content'];
```

should now work.

The alternative is to just access the data through the array index:

`echo $pagecontent[0]['content']['title']`

which isn't as "cake" like.

to expand = `query()` returns data in a different structure than using `find` or `read`. There's other ways you can do this too.

```
$this->Content->id = 1;
$this->set('pagecontent', $this->Content->read(array('title', 'content')));
```

should also be valid.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, although I have revised it to meet your answer. I've uploaded more information to my question.

Comment: Thank you for that and for explaining why it wasn't working :)